# Relation between order $n$, chromatic number $\chi(G)$ and diameter $\text{diam}(G)$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

Is the following fact true?

For a connected graph of order $n$, chromatic number $\chi(G)$ and diameter diam$(G)$ we have $$\chi(G) + \text{diam}(G) \leq n+1$$

Answer (score 6):

Yes: if a graph has diameter $d$, then it contains an induced path on $d+1$ vertices (the shortest path between some two vertices at distance $d$ from each other). You can give the vertices on that path $2$ colors, then use $n-d-1$ distinct colors on the remaining vertices, so $\chi(G) \le n-d+1$, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This has been proven by Nettleton around 1960, in his article [some generalized theorems on connectivity](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/B073E7FFAC316CF4CC94E48EC399FBD8/S0008414X0001018Xa.pdf/some_generalized_theorems_on_connectivity.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjD76X746TqAhUMOSsKHYIUDPUQFjABegQIAhAC&usg=AOvVaw18_2g3nFYlf75qaxPUn1VE)

See theorem 4.1 item 2. The proof seems too long to be reproduced here.